# Error in Call intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to learn android by making some basic apps. I tried to create the calling app, which will call a number given as input. THe code compiles fine, but when I click on Call, it displays an error and opens the Parcel class. I'm unable to get around this problem. Please suggest a fix. thnks

My MainActvitiy file-

```
package com.example.call;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button b;
EditText e1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String abc=e1.getText().toString();
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+abc));
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My activity_main file-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.call.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:text="Call home" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you have any error , first you should look at LogCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this permission to your `AndroidManifest` file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Forget to add permissions in the manifest file

Comment: @user3576010 : good to hear that, it would be nice if you mark it as an accpeted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like You Forgot to add Permission in the AndroidMenifest File.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```